# How to filter in Wireshark on a dynamic field name

Tags: filter, lua, wireshark

I have a protocol where the data payload is in a structured array. 
example:

```
DataBlock 1:
   name: xxx
   city: xxx
   origin: xxx
DataBlock 2:
   name: xxx
   city: xxx
   origin: xxx
DataBlock 3:
   name: xxx
   city: xxx
   origin: xxx
```

and this is all within one frame in a Protocol named ServerBlocks...

My wireshark filter to find all ServerBlocks is just

```
ServerBlocks
```

My filter to find name in DataBlock 3 is...

```
ServerBlocks.3.name
```

The problem i am having is i want to apply a wildcard to the field. I need this because i dont know what the index number is for name == 'John'

What i am looking for is:

```
ServerBlocks.*.name == 'John'
```

The array in each ServerBlocks frame could be of different size so ill never know how many indexes there are to filter on. John could be index 1 or index X, but i just want to apply a display filter on ServerBlocks where one of the DataBlocks has name == 'John'

I have looked in:
https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters 
and https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html

and havent found anything that could help.

FYI:
I am able to change the Lua defined ProtoField's so the array index doesnt need to be in the middle of the field but it could be at the end or the beginning too...example:

```
ServerBlocks.name.1
```

or

```
1.ServerBlocks.name
```

but even with this flexibility im unsure of how to filter properly so i can find where name == John without knowing the exact index

Answer (score 1):

I would dispense with the indices for field names and just use a common filter for them all.  And if `ServerBlocks` represents *all* blocks, you should probably have a collapsible tree for each block, with a summary line for each one so you don't necessarily need to expand the tree to easily see the information it contains.  In this way, you can filter for the name in any block.

So, instead of displaying the blocks as you have, you'd have something like:

```
[+] DataBlocks: 3 blocks
```

And if you expand that tree, you'd see:

```
[-] DataBlocks: 3 blocks
    [+] DataBlock 1: name1, city1, origin1
    [+] DataBlock 2: name2, city2, origin2
    [+] DataBlock 3: name3, city3, origin3
```

And of course if you expand a particular DataBlock, then you'd see the individual details as you've provided above.

Filtering for a particular name would then use a filter such as `myproto.datablocks.datablock.name == foo`.  That would match all packets where the name was *foo*, regardless of which datablock it was in.

So how do you apply an enumeration for each block while still using the same filter name?  First, you either need to know how many blocks there are ahead of time, or maybe you just keep looping through the data until you run out of bytes - this all depends on your protocol protocol and its encoding.  Here, I'll assume you have a way to determine how many blocks there are, in which case, the following ***pseudo***-code may be helpful to you:

```
blocks_tree = myproto_tree:add(datablocks, tvbuf(offset, datablocks_len))

for i = 1, numblocks do
    datablock_len = TODO
    block_tree = blocks_tree:add(datablock, tvbuf(offset, datablock_len):set_text(
        string.format("DataBlock %d: ", i)

    block_tree:add(datablock_name, tvbuf(offset, namelen))
    block_tree:append_text(tvbuf(offset, namelen):string() .. ", ")

    block_tree:add(datablock_city, tvbuf(offset + namelen, citylen))
    block_tree:append_text(tvbuf(offset + namelen, citylen):string() .. ", ")

    block_tree:add(datablock_origin, tvbuf(offset + namelen + citylen, originlen))
    block_tree:append_text(tvbuf(offset + namelen + citylen, originlen):string())

    offset = offset + namelen + citylen + originlen
end
```

If you don't know `datablocks_len` ahead of time, you can use `blocks_tree:set_len(somelen)` later, once you do figure out how long it is.  I have also assumed that name, city and origin are all strings and that you know how to determine the length of each string (i.e., namelen, citylen and originlen).

Refer to the Wireshark [Lua](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua) and related wiki pages for more information, including some sample scripts that may or may not be of use to you here.  And don't forget about [Wireshark’s Lua API Reference Manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wsluarm_modules.html).

Comment: using the same filter name is what solved it for me. im able to do the looping and determine the size of the array no issue. didnt realize i can have the same filter name for multiple ProtoFields. Thanks!